# c# printing PDF in Multiple setting output?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I have a .net application in c# where I'm trying to print using a pdf document on the left side and a text description on the right side.  So far I've been successful in combining the 2 outputs into one pdf file, but am stumped on how to programmatically do it so that when I go to print, then in the Page Sizing & Handling section, select "Multiple" and set pages per sheet to 2.

My guess is it's a process print feature somewhere but can't seem to find any examples nor clear documentation to do so.  Please advise, thanks.

[image]

Comment: are you trying to have the pdf on one page and the text comments on another?

Comment: No, same sheet of paper.  On the pdf itself the text is really a separate page that was merged with the document so to share the same print job.

Comment: What report building tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using iTextSharp which uses a ticket template to fill in the blanks, so no report building tool that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set pages per sheet from the backend rather than print/ print dialog you have to use PrintTicket Class [System.Printing]. this classs have lots of property and events that can allow us to do lots of printing and printing job related stuff using c# code. there is also many classes related to printing in this name space[ may you know about the xps in windows when you going to print may you see option print to xps it is belongs to Print Schema class]

you can read more about it from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.printing.printticket.aspx

Comment: Hmmm, I couldn't seem to find the PrintTicket class in my System.Print nor my System.Drawing.Print references, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm using c# in Visual Studio 2013 which supports .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: Turned out I needed to add reference to ReachFramework.dll

The part I'm trying to determine is how to tie this in with my print document since they are referenced from separate classes:

            PrintTicket ticket = new PrintTicket();
            ticket.PagesPerSheet = 2;

Comment: dear i have written name space its inside the "System.Printing" you have to add reference to your project.

Comment: While this may answer my question regarding using the PrintTicket class to utilize the multiple pages per sheet, I'm going to post another question I'm rather stuck on, I'll link here once ready.

Comment: Here's the new question posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38852347/c-sharp-printing-pdf-outputting-2-pages-per-sheet